# Angular and CSS - seeing the background in Chrome Developer Tools but can't find it anywhere

Tags: css, primeng

It's amazing how Angular can hide css, so I don't know how to change a certain color. I am using Angular with Prime ng, specifically I use `<p-selectbutton>` and I can't find how to change the background for the selected option. Where can I change this? I searched the whole project for the text `186ba0` which is the color for this background, and I couldn't find it! Anyway, this is the screenshot for the caught background CSS element:
[image]

Comment: Override it in your own CSS.

Comment: I tried it. It cannot be overriden.

Comment: _"It cannot be overriden"_ ?? I doubt that very much. If you use a more specific selector or use !important it will work.

Comment: thanks ! important worked.

Comment: My question is what would've happened if I had !important also on the place where the blue color (186ba0) was applied? I wouldn't know where to find this file in order to change it. I can't find this CSS anywhere.

Comment: Then you would have to use a more specific selector than the one you are trying to override.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the original angular file's not a good practice. Did you try to override it using an !important statement?

If you did, try changing the original file, but beware, if you update your angular application, you'll lose this changes.

Comment: I couldn't even found the original version! :)

Comment: Check on your "Network" tab. See if you can find which css files are being consumed by the app.